# Prevent the keyboard from opening automatically SearchView

Tags: android, kotlin, focus, searchview

good morning, I have problems preventing the keyboard from opening automatically when I start an activity.

I have already implemented these three options.

1. Manifest change in

   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
2. SOFT_INPUT at onResume method.

   window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)
3. cleaning the focus of the SearchView.

   searhView?.clearFocus()

Any advice? Please.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

use this attribute in xml to address this issue